# Category Wise product to be displayed?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalog, products

I want to display the products according to the categories and make them list of all the products related to that category.

So far I have tried using this code:

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="18" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

And in this category there are 10 products.

But the output gives me **There are no products matching the selection**.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: please tell us in more detail what you want what you have tried so far

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I have edited the question once have a check.

Comment: You may need to whitelist the `catalog/product_list` block.

Comment: @Ritu check my answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I have done according to your answer but no luck. Still it shows the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CE 1.9.2.2** includes all the changes from the recent-patch `SUPEE-6788`, one of which was restrict the blocks that can be used in CMS blocks, pages, emails (etc...) by default.

Fortunately you can whitelist additional blocks through the admin under `System > Permissions > (Blocks | Variables)`

- `System > Permissions > Blocks`
- `Add New Block`
- Block Name: `catalog/product_list`
- Is Allowed : `Yes`

Don't forget to add `cms/block` if it's not already there.

Don't forget to clear the `cache` too

[image]

Comment: Bilal I didn't get this point "Don't forget to add cms/block if it's not already there."

Comment: i have added a screen shot to ma answer please take a look

Comment: if this doesn't work try reindexing

Answer (score 0):

I got your point

1) login to admin panel

2) go to `System->permission->Blocks`

3) click `add new Block` button

4) add this block `catalog/product_list` and set enable in dropdown and save

5) clear magento cache and check again

Comment: I have done according to your answer but no luck. Still it shows the same thing.

Comment: @ritu Do reindexing  from System->index managment

Comment: @Ritu If Its done because of my answer then feel free to mark as accepted